# Let $f : A \to B$ be a function. If $f$ is surjective, injective, or bijective what can we say about $|A|$ in comparison to $|B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f : A \to B$ be a function, where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. Recall that a function is a
certain kind of relation, and a relation is a certain kind of set, so it makes sense to talk about
the cardinality of the function, $|f|$.

(a) What can we say about $|f|$ in comparison to $|A|$?

(b) If $f$ is surjective, injective, or bijective what can we say about $|A|$ in comparison to $|B|$?

---

Solution:

For $(a)$ we can say $f$ size would be $|B|^{|A|}$ if we were to do the cartesian product. I'm not sure what they are asking for B, I do know that surjective (or onto) means for every $b \in B$ there is atleast one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. One-to-one or injective is if every element $b \in B$, there is at most one element $a \in A$ that maps onto b. And bijective is if its one to one and onto, meaning $|A| = |B|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the cartesian relation is not a function. All we know is that every element of the domain $A$ must be mapped once and only once, so for each element of $A$, there is an element of $A\times B$ in $f$. As such,  $|f|=|A|$.

For part b, if the function is injective, we know that every member of $A$ maps to a unique member of $B$. That means that $|A|\leq|B|$. Likewise, if the function is surjective, then all $B$ are mapped to, but multiple elements of $A$ can map to the same element of $B$. As such, $|A|\geq|B|$. Both of these conditions together ensure that $|A|=|B|$

Comment: Note that a function **is** a relation, but a specific kind of one. Also for the first part, a function means that each element in $A$ is maps **once**

Comment: my finger press enter by mistake, refresh to see the rest

Comment: @Holo See edits!

Answer (score 0):

For (a), $f\in B^A$, i.e. $f$ is given. So why would $|f|=|B|^{|A|}$?

Think about the definition: $f$ is a function if it is a relation(subset of $A\times B$) such that $\forall x\in A\exists!y\in B((x,y)\in f)$ where $\exists !$ is "exists unique". Now can you tell what $|f|$ is? try to take an example

---

After you answer (a) the rest of the questions will be clearer.